# Confusing with Regular Expressions repeaing parts

Tags: javascript, regex

I am really confused with Regular Expressions repeating parts with curly braces. Consider the following example:

```
var dateTime = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}/;
console.log(dateTime.test("30/1/2003 8:45"));
// true
```

Now if I change 30 to 300000 and 45 to 455555, I'll get true again! Other parts between outer numbers are ok and the result is as expected.

Can somebody help me find the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You're not matching the beginning and end of the _String_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not matching the beginning and end of the *String* (`^` and `$`) so it's just finding a match anywhere in the *String* which still happens, and then giving true.

```
300000/1/2003 8:455555
    dd/m/yyyy h:mm
```

You probably want

```
/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}$/;
```

Or to be even more exact;

```
/^(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4} (?:0?\d|1\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$/;
```

- `(?:pattern)` non capture group
- `pattern?` the `n` in `pattern` is optional
- `[1-9]` character class; a number ranging from `1` to `9`
- `pattern1|pattern2` either `pattern1` or `pattern2`
- `[12]` character class; either `1` or `2`
- `\d` same as `[0-9]`
- `pattern{4}` the `n` in `pattern` happens `4` times

Comment: It doesn't look like your regex matches day numbers from 10 to 19. Also, why go to the trouble of matching all the numbers, but allowing any two digits for the minutes of the time? 12:87 is not a valid time!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol silly me, lets fix that **edit** and now I've permitted having `00` hours too for 24h times

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that when you change 30 to 30000, the last two zeroes(00) of 30000 are matched and with 45555 the matching is stopped with first two digits(45) and the rest of the string is not matched.
To stop that from happening, you have to indicate that the string must begin and end with regex specified.
This can be done using [`anchors`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). 
Like this -

```
var dateTime = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}$/;
                ^                                     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not matching the whole string, just part of it - using the `test` function, that's enough to return `True`.

Try this instead:

```
/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}$/
```

The `^` anchor matches the beginning of the string, the `$` one matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more useful information about a match by using `string.match(regex)` rather than `regex.test(string)`.

In this case, you'd see that it's matching `00/1/2003 8:45` because you did not use `^` and `$` to mark the start and end of the subject string, respectively.